# 32 bit QGIS 2.10 Problems with GDAL WMS TMS Google Maps layer

Tags: qgis, gdal, wms, tile-map-service

I have been using GDAL WMS layers to view various base maps in QGIS. I am using this technique rather than OpenLayers because with this I can reproject GDAL WMS layers as needed.

When I get close to the max zoom on my Google layer my images become discolored (sometimes all in blues, other times yellows).  I have checked my layer settings to ensure that my color band settings are correct.

I only have this problem when using a Google Maps layer, I have not seen any problems with other GDAL WMS layers.

I have checked for this problem in both the 32 bit and 64 bit versions of QGIS on multiple Windows 7 computers.  I only observed this problem on the 32 bit version.

Also is there any way to make QGIS log my tile requests?

The layer XML is below:

```
<GDAL_WMS>
  <Service name="TMS">   
    <ServerUrl>http://mt.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&amp;x=${x}&amp;y=${y}&amp;z=${z}</ServerUrl>
  </Service>
  <DataWindow>
    <UpperLeftX>-20037508.34</UpperLeftX>
    <UpperLeftY>20037508.34</UpperLeftY>
    <LowerRightX>20037508.34</LowerRightX>
    <LowerRightY>-20037508.34</LowerRightY>
    <TileLevel>19</TileLevel>
    <TileCountX>1</TileCountX>
    <TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
    <YOrigin>top</YOrigin>
  </DataWindow>
  <Projection>EPSG:3857</Projection>
  <BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
  <BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
  <BandsCount>3</BandsCount>
 <Cache>
<Depth>2</Depth>    
<Extension>.jpg</Extension>
</Cache>
</GDAL_WMS>
```